# How do I retrieve a list of my corpora using watson-developer-cloud python sdk?

Tags: python, ibm-watson

I created a single corpora like so:

```
from watson_developer_cloud import ConceptInsightsV2 as ConceptInsights
concept_insights = ConceptInsights(
    username='<My Service User>',
    password='<My Service Pass>')
create_corpora = concept_insights.create_corpus('Test Corpora One!')
```

I don't receive an error, and if I attempt to run the code again I get the expected exception telling me that the corpus already exists.

Now, how do I print out just my corpora? I attempted to do this:

```
print(concept_insights.list_corpora())
```

But, it returns a large list of public corpora and buried in the middle of the list of dictionaries is my single corpora. How do I get just *my* list? I can retrieve just my list using the [`getAccountCorpora`](https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/apis/concept-insights-v2#!/corpora/getAccountCorpora) function on the API explorer. Is there a way to pass the account id via python and achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality was missing from the Python SDK but has since been added (thanks to your question), so you can now do:

`print(concept_insights.list_corpora(account='<My Account>'))`